# dotnetbrowswer printing related issues

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I am currently evaluating the dotnetbrowser control.   One of my requirements is to print the HTML as a PDF.   I am able to get the PDF to generate but it does not seems to be ignoring the print media type in my css.   My css looks like the following:

```
@@media print {
    div.divHeader {
        width: 100%;
        display: table-header-group;
    }
    div.divFooter {
        width: 100%;
        display: table-footer-group;
    }
}
```

None of these settings are honored when I print the document.   Does the control support media types?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is observed due to the extra `@` symbol.
I have checked the media print type and it worked fine.
Here is a CSS which I have tested

```
@media print {
    @page :left {
        margin: 4cm;
    }
    @page :right {
        margin: 4cm;
    }
}
```

With the extra `@` symbol, the media type is ignored.

The link to the `@media` specification:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media